# Repast Simphony 3D GIS

Tags: repast-simphony

I am using Repast Simphony for a project that involves airspace and would like to have agents move in 3D continuous space above a GIS projection that has static ground-based agents. Currently, I have separate `Geography` and `ContinuousSpace` projections in the same context and move agents simultaneously in both projections, but the GIS display is only 2D in terms of agent motion.

I noticed that the `Geometry` objects used to set position in a `Geography` have a `Coordinate.z` fields, but setting the `z` value to anything other than `NaN` does nothing. I haven't found anything in the docs about this.

I plan on implementing the `Projection` interface and making my own projection, as I cannot implement the `Geography` and `ContinuousSpace` in the same class due to conflicting method signatures ('getAdder'). This seems a rather daunting task, so I figured it would be worth checking if there are any better ways of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can elevate point markers in the 3D GIS display by overriding the 
repast.simphony.visualization.gis3D.style.MarkStyle() method

`public double getElevation(T obj)`

that will place the point marker at the elevation specified in meters in the 3D GIS display.  The JTS Coordinate object can store a z-value as you indicated, but none of the Geotools or JTS spatial math use this value as the CRS transforms are all based on 2D topography.  I believe the getElevation() in the style specifies elevation relative to ground and not sea level.  You can provide a method in your agents that provides the current elevation to the style, and then just have the style return the agent.getElevation().